# Storing data in customise table after google authentication

Tags: laravel-5.8

by default this data is stored in "users" table but i need to store data in "new_users" table what and where i need to update ???

```
SocialGoogleAccount extends Model
 {

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'provider_user_id', 'provider'];

    public function newuser()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    }

my controller is 

    public function redirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }
    /**
     * Return a callback method from google api.
     *
     * @return callback URL from google
     */
    public function callback(SocialGoogleAccountService $service)
    {
        $user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver('google')->user());
        auth()->login($user);
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }
```